# Operaciones matemáticas usando fechas en vbscript

Tags: vbscript

La plataforma de  programación es en InduSoft Web Studio.
Estoy tratando de hacer Operaciones Matemática utilizando Fechas  en vbScript .
No encuentro una función que logre hacer lo que quiero.
Que estoy haciendo:  Operación Matemática  10:58:13-11:00:19

```
$Incio_Parada_Hora = “10:58:13”
$Final_Parada_Hora=$Time
$Total_Tiempo_Parada)= TimeValue($Final_Parada_Hora) - TimeValue($Incio_Parada_Hora)
```

El resultado de la operación es esta: 6.94444444444553E-05
No entiendo a que se refiere ese resultado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probablemente lo controlarás mejor con la función [DATEDIFF](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/datediff-function) que te ofrece la diferencia entre dos datetime en la unidad que quieras. Por ejemplo en segundos.

Si pones

`$Total_Tiempo_Parada)= DATEDIFF("s", TimeValue($Final_Parada_Hora), TimeValue($Incio_Parada_Hora))`

obtienes un entero correspondiente a los segundos transcurridos entre uno y otro valor, luego lo puedes ajustar a minutos o lo que desees.